# How to run command on save in Sublime Text 3?

Tags: sublimetext3

Sublime Text offers built-in commands, such as `paste`, `new_window`, `toggle_comment` etc. In addition, some plugins offer their own commands that can be used for key binding.

Can I force any of these commands to be ran on file save? The reason I need is because I'd like to run CSScomb on file save instead of / in addition to having key binding for it. The command name is `css_comb`.

Comment: Check out [this package](https://github.com/klaascuvelier/SublimeCommandOnSave) which seems to do what you want.

Comment: For some reason this package is no longer available through Package Manager. But even if it was, it doesn't run Sublime commands, but bash commands.

Comment: The plugin of that package gives you the key. You only need to do a plugin that extends [EventListener](https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/3/api_reference.html#sublime_plugin.EventListener) and override `on_pre_save` or `on_post_save` method with your custom code (e.g. `view.run_command('css_comb')`. Also some sublime packages have an option to run them before save (e.g.: some javascript package that indent code before saving the file), I don't know if css_comb have this setting.

Comment: Do I need to create my own plugin for this simple task?

Comment: I don't think there is an easier way, I haven't searched for existent packages, but the one mentioned by saadq has all the code needed, you need 4 of that lines and add your desired code (1 line).

Comment: Take a look also at [this package](https://github.com/twolfson/sublime-hooks).

Comment: @sergioFC Please add an answer, I will accept it. This package worked for me!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[Sublime-hooks](https://github.com/twolfson/sublime-hooks) package allows you to run packages based on event (on new, on save, etc.), so you can use it to achieve your goal. Just add this code to CSS syntax settings:

```
"on_pre_save_language": [
    {
        "command": "css_comb"
    }
]
```

If you are familiar with plugins maybe you can make a plugin that extends [EventListener](https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/3/api_reference.html#sublime_plugin.EventListener) and override `on_post_save` or `on_pre_save` methods.

Comment: Note that if you set up hooks using project settings, you _must_ open the project using the Project > Open Project… menu item. There is presently no indication that a window is in Project mode vs Folder mode, but if you've just opened a folder, the project settings won't be loaded. More in [this Sublime Text issue](https://github.com/sublimehq/sublime_text/issues/5819).