# How to run a shell command after saving file in Sublime 3

Tags: sublimetext3

I've been trying to create a custom shell command to run after saving the file im working on. The command should run in the same location of the file.

I've came up with this, under user-preferences, but with no success.:

```
 "on_post_save_user": [
{
  "cmd": ["shell command"]
}
```

.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to run command on save in Sublime Text 3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31494950/how-to-run-command-on-save-in-sublime-text-3)

Comment: Your answer looks like you're using [this package](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Hooks); the command that it's executing is a Sublime command, not a shell command. As such you want to execute the `exec` command with arguments of `shell_cmd` and put your command in there.

Comment: @OdatNurd not a duplicate. I found that thread but I still couldnt get it to work. Did you mean something like
`"exec": ["google-chrome"]` ? cause I still cant get it to work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on your question, I'm going to assume that you're using the [Hooks](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Hooks) package to be able to run arbitrary commands based on events. If you haven't installed that package yet, then you'll need to do that too; the items talked about here are not available in core Sublime.

This package can execute any arbitrary command that you want, but note that this means *Sublime* commands; that is commands provided either by the core of Sublime or by packages and plugins that you have installed. Thus including the name of a shell command will not work; Sublime silently ignores commands that you tell it to run that it doesn't know about.

That said, the `exec` command is available directly in any Sublime installation and can execute any arbitrary shell command or program that you tell it to. This command is what is used to execute a [build system](https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/3/build_systems.html), for example.

In fact, most of the keys available in a Build system by default (excluding the keys that tell Sublime when your build should apply) are actually [arguments to the exec command](https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/3/build_systems.html#exec_options) that tell it what to execute.

Of particular interest to you is the `shell_cmd` argument, which takes any arbitrary command that you might enter in a command prompt and executes it.

Based on the documentation of the package in question, the configuration option you want would be something like this:

```json
"on_post_save_user": [
  {
    // Runs `exec` command
    "command": "exec",

    // Invokes `exec` with `shell_cmd="google-chrome"`
    "args": {
      "shell_cmd": "google-chrome"
    },

    // Runs `exec` via `window.run_command`
    "scope": "window"
  }
]
```

With the caveat that I don't use this particular package and I can't verify that this is all that might be required, this tells the package to run the `exec` command (which is indeed a `window` command), telling it to execute `google-chrome`.

Other options may be required to `exec` to do what you want, depending on what that is. It's also unclear from the package documentation whether it supports the standard build system variables like `$file` to represent the current file or not, which may or may not be a problem.

Note also that since the `exec` command is what executes build systems, if `show_panel_on_build` is turned on in your user preferences (which it is by default unless you turn it off), the `exec` command will open a panel at the bottom of the window to tell you what the command you're running is doing.

Comment: Nov. 2021/Sublime build 4121: I couldn't seem to use "$file" though the exec docs indicate it is available as a variable. I tried: `"args": { "cmd": ["hindent", "$file"] }` and also with an escaped $file: `"\\$file"`. The variable wasn't being expanded, so hindent received it as a literal string. Not sure if it's an issue with the Hooks package or with the exec command.

Comment: Update on my previous comment: It is an issue with exec, at the very least. I tried `self.window.run_command("exec", {"cmd": ["hindent", "$file"]})` in a custom command .py file, and the variable wasn't being expanded. For anyone requiring the use of variables, such as $file, a working alternative is to [obtain the file_name() programmatically](https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/api_reference.html#sublime.View) in a custom command .py file and do your work in the custom command (e.g. call `run_command("exec", ...)`. You can then provide this custom command's name to the Hooks package.

Comment: @nishanthshanmugham the `exec` command indeed doesn't expand variables itself; the `build` command does that before it invokes `exec` (or any build `target` key, which is what `exec` is generally used for); if you want a version of `exec` that will work for something like this, the following implements a drop in replacement that behaves as `exec` but while also expanding arguments: https://github.com/STealthy-and-haSTy/SublimeScraps/blob/master/plugins/menu_exec.py